# What is the derived functors of multivariable functor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $T$ be a functor with $p$ variables with some contravariant and some covariant. Let $s$ variable be active variables of $T$ and those $s$ variables are to be resolved by either projective or injective resoltuion according to either contravariance or covariance respectively. The rest variables are left untouched.

$\textbf{Q:}$ What does it mean to derive those derived functors? Say $T(X_1,\dots, X_s,Y_{s+1},\dots, Y_p)$ is the functor with $X_i$ to be resolved. Does it mean take "higher dimensional" complex formed by the corresponding resolution of $X_i$, produce a total complex as in 2 complex case via taking $\sum_{j\leq s}i_j=n$ for indices, and compute its homology or cohomology?

Ref. Cartan, Eilenberg, Homological Algebra, Chpt V, Sec 8, Partial Derived Fucnctors.(pg94)

Answer (score 1):

For concreteness, let's take a right derived functor of $T$. Dualize *mutatis mutandis* for left derived functors.

In the context I'm aware of, you want to have the following additional hypothesis on $T$:

> We say that $T$ is *right balanced* if:
>
> 1. when you replace a covariant variable with an injective module, then $T$ is exact in each of the remaining variables.
> 2. when you replace a contravariant variable with a projective module, then $T$ is exact in each of the remaining variables.

Under this hypothesis, one can show that to compute a right derived functor of $T$, all one must do is choose any variable slot and treat $T$ as a single-variable functor in that slot, with all other slots fixed. Then you just build a derived functor of the single-variable functor like you always do: take an acyclic resolution, compute (co)homology. (The canonical example is treating the bifunctor $\operatorname{Hom}(-,-)$ as a functor $\operatorname{Hom}(-,B)$ or as $\operatorname{Hom}(A,-)$; both give you $\operatorname{Ext}$.)

A priori, this would give you different derived functors if you choose different slots, but one can show that, with the *right balanced* hypothesis, all the right derived functors are naturally isomorphic. (In the case of $-\otimes-$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(-,-)$ this is called "balancing" $\operatorname{Tor}$ and $\operatorname{Ext}$ and involves a quaint application of spectral sequences via a result called the Acyclic Assembly Lemma.) Below is the general computation:

Let $T$ be a right balanced functor, without loss of generality with all covariant variables. Choose $i\in\{2,\ldots,p\}$; we show that $R^{*}T(\widehat{X_{1}},X_{2},\ldots,X_{p})(X_{1})\cong R^{*}T(X_{1},\ldots,\widehat{X_{i}},\ldots,X_{p})(X_{i})$, where this notation means the (single-variable) functor with hatted-variable free and all others fixed.

Choose injective resolutions $X_{1}\xrightarrow{\varepsilon}I^{\bullet}$ and $X_{i}\xrightarrow{\eta}J^{\bullet}$. Fix $X_{j}$ for all $j\not\in\{1,i\}$, and write $T(-,-)=T(-,X_{2},\ldots,X_{i-1},-,X_{i+1},\ldots,X_{p})$. In other words, we're slightly abusing notation and just forgetting about all the fixed variables; they are absorbed as part of the functor. Form the first quadrant double cochain complex:

$\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}
\newcommand{\ua}[1]{\uparrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}$
\begin{array}{c}
\vdots &  & \vdots &  & \vdots &  & \vdots &  & \vdots &  &  \\
\ua{} & & \vdots & & \ua{} & & \ua{} & & \ua{} & &  \\
T(X_{1},J^{2}) &  & \vdots &  & T(I^{0},J^{2}) & \ras{d} & T(I^{1},J^{2}) & \ras{d} & T(I^{2},J^{2}) & \ras{} & \cdots \\
\ua{} & & \vdots & & \ua{d} & & \ua{-d} & & \ua{d} & &  \\
T(X_{1},J^{1}) &  & \vdots &  & T(I^{0},J^{1}) & \ras{d} & T(I^{1},J^{1}) & \ras{d} & T(I^{2},J^{1}) & \ras{} & \cdots \\
\ua{} & & \vdots & & \ua{d} & & \ua{-d} & & \ua{d} & &  \\
T(X_{1},J^{0}) &  & \vdots &  & T(I^{0},J^{0}) & \ras{d} & T(I^{1},J^{0}) & \ras{d} & T(I^{2},J^{0}) & \ras{} & \cdots \\
 &  & \cdot &  & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
 &  & &  & T(I^{0},X_{i}) & \ra{} & T(I^{1},X_{i}) & \ra{} & T(I^{2},X_{i}) & \ra{} & \cdots \\
\end{array}
where the differentials in the horizontal direction are the images of $d:I^{p}\to I^{p+1}$ under the functor $T(-,B)$ where $B$ is fixed, and the differentials in the vertical direction use the sign trick; i.e., they are $(-1)^{p}$ times the images of $d:J^{q}\to J^{q+1}$ under the functor $T(A,-)$ where $A$ is fixed.

Call the double complexes formed from $I$ and $J$, from $I$ and $X_{i}$, and from $X_{1}$ and $J$:

1. $T(I,J)$,
2. $T(I,X_{i})$, and
3. $T(X_{1},J)$,

respectively. This means you should think of the above double cochain complex as
$\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}
\newcommand{\ua}[1]{\uparrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}$
\begin{array}{c}
T(X_{1},J)&\vdots&T(I,J)\\
&\cdot&\cdots\\
&&T(I,X_{i})
\end{array}
(Those dotted lines are there to help you compartmentalize.)

Now consider the double complex $C$ obtained from $T(I,J)$ by adding $T(X_{1},J)[-1]$ in the column $p=-1$, as we have in the picture. (It's just forgetting the $T(I,X_{i})$ piece.) The translate $\operatorname{Tot}(C)[+1]$ is the mapping cone of the map induced by $\varepsilon$ from $\operatorname{Tot}(T(X_{1},J))=T(X_{1},J)$ to $\operatorname{Tot}(T(I,J))$. This induced map is a quasi-isomorphism if and only if its mapping cone is exact; i.e., the complex $\operatorname{Tot}(C)[+1]$ is acyclic, which is the case if and only if the nonshifted $\operatorname{Tot}(C)$ is.

Since $T$ is a right balanced functor, covariant in all variables, and $J^{\bullet}$ are injective modules, $T(-,J)$ is an exact functor. Thus, every row of $C$ is exact, and as $C$ is a right half-plane with exact rows, the Acyclic Assembly Lemma implies that $\operatorname{Tot}(C)$ is acyclic, as desired. Thus, the map induced by $\varepsilon$ is a quasi-isomorphism; that is,
\begin{align*}
H^{*}(\operatorname{Tot}(T(I,J)))\cong H^{*}(T(X_{1},J))=R^{*}T(X_{1},-)(X_{i})=R^{*}T(X_{1},\ldots,\widehat{X_{i}},\ldots,X_{p})(X_{i}).
\end{align*}

Similarly, the double complex $D$ obtained from $T(I,J)$ by adding $T(I,X_{i})[-1]$ in the row $q=-1$ (take the picture and forget $T(X_{1},J)$) yields a totalization $\operatorname{Tot}(D)$. The translate $\operatorname{Tot}(D)[+1]$ is the mapping cone of the map induced by $\eta$ from $\operatorname{Tot}(T(I,X_{i}))=T(I,X_{i})$ to $\operatorname{Tot}(T(I,J))$. We again show that $\operatorname{Tot}(D)$ is acyclic to get the desired isomorphism on cohomology.

Indeed, as $T$ is right balanced, covariant, and $I^{\bullet}$ are injective, $T(I,-)$ is exact, so every column of $D$ is exact, and as $D$ is an upper half-plane with exact columnds, $\operatorname{Tot}(D)$ is acyclic, thanks to the Acyclic Assembly Lemma. Therefore, we may conclude
\begin{align*}
H^{*}(\operatorname{Tot}(T(I,J)))\cong H^{*}(T(I,X_{i}))=R^{*}T(-,X_{i})(X_{1})=R^{*}T(\widehat{X_{i}},X_{2},\ldots,X_{p}).
\end{align*}
By transitivity,
\begin{align*}
R^{*}T(X_{1},\ldots,\widehat{X_{i}},\ldots,X_{p})(X_{i})\cong R^{*}T(\widehat{X_{1}},X_{2},\ldots,X_{p})(X_{1}),
\end{align*}
as we wished to show, and therefore the derived functor of $T$ is well-defined. You get the same result independent of which single-variable functor you derive.

Check out Weibel's *An introduction to homological algebra*, section 2.7, for the meat of this discussion.